# Why will my django model data not display in html

Tags: python, django

Following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=obZMr9URmVI&t=914s) tutorial, I am creating a simple ecommerce website. I have data stored in  a Django model, and I am calling it in my view, but it will not display in my html. Basically, I want it to create one of the boxes bellow for every donation in the donation model, but it will not work. Can someone please help me? I know this seems like an easy fix, I just can't wrap my head around it. My code is down bellow.

View:

```
def availablesupplies(request):
    donations = Donation.objects.all()
    context = {'donations':donations}
    return render(request, 'availablesupplies.html')
```

Model:

```
class Donation(models.Model):
  title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
  phonenumber = models.CharField(max_length=12)
  category = models.CharField(max_length=20)
  quantity  = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True,)
  location = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True,)       
  description = models.TextField()
  datedonated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
  user = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
    )
```

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
        {% for donation in donations %}
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            <img class="thumbnail" src="{% static 'images/gooddeedplaceholderimage.png' %}">
            <div class="box-element product">
                <h6><strong>Product</strong></h6>
                <hr>

                <button  class="btn btn-outline-secondary add-btn">Add to Cart</button>
                <a class="btn btn-outline-success" href="#">View</a>
                <h4 style="display: inline-block; float: right"><strong>$20</strong></h4>

            </div>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>

{% endblock content %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to *pass* the context object to the render engine:

```
def availablesupplies(request):
    donations = Donation.objects.all()
    context = {'donations':donations}
    #                                  pass the context ↓
    return render(request, 'availablesupplies.html', context)
```

Comment: oh lol thanks, I didn't know I forgot that, its something so simple and easy